# Flex Object Reference Through Variable Value

Tags: apache-flex, object, reference

Is it possible to reference an object using a variable value?


For example, I have a function that is supposed to hide an image and add that image to an inventory list when the item is clicked.

All the image info is stored in an object (name, imgSource, visible, x, y);


I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var item:Object = new Object();

        // name, imgSource, xPos, yPos, visible
        [Bindable]
        public var knife:ItemInfo = new ItemInfo('knife','knife.png',50,50,true);

        public function addItem(evnt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // I want "item" to be equal to the object "knife"
            item = evnt.currentTarget.name;
            item.visible = false;
            inventory.addItem(item.name);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image source="{knife.source}" name="knife" 
         x="{knife.xPos}" y="{knife.yPos}" 
         visible="{knife.visible}"
         click="addItem(event);" />
```

I want "item" to stand for knife so that I could change knife.visible, knife.xPos, ect.

Is that possible, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why does `item` have to be an `Object` ? Why cannot it be of type `ItemInfo` ?

Also `item = evnt.currentTarget` should work if you want `item` to reference the `knife` image that was clicked.

**Update**

ToolInfo ? or ItemInfo ?

Anyway `evnt.currentTarget` is of type object. Try casting it to type ItemInfo.

`evnt.currentTarget as ItemInfo`

Comment: If i make "item" a type ItemInfo, I get this error:
1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type components:ToolInfo.

Comment: that didn't work either
error: cannot access property "visible", but I guess I did figure out a different way to do it. 
Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change the values of the object on click is just to pass the object itself into the addItem() function. The problem with this is that I have to preselect which variable goes into the function at what time, but for this purpose it works great.

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    public var item:Object = new Object();

    // name, imgSource, xPos, yPos, visible
    [Bindable]
    public var knife:ItemInfo = new ItemInfo('knife','knife.png',50,50,true);

    public function addItem(item:ItemInfo):void
    {
        item.visible = false;
        inventory.addItem(item.name);
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Image source="{knife.source}" name="knife" 
     x="{knife.xPos}" y="{knife.yPos}" 
     visible="{knife.visible}"
     click="addItem(knife);" />
```